# Can printf get replaced by puts automatically in a C program?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int puts(const char* str)
{
    return printf("Hiya!\n");
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs "Hiya!" when run. Could someone explain why?

The compile line is:
`gcc main.c`

EDIT: it's now pure C, and any extraneous stuff has been removed from the compile line.

Comment: It optimization that does not depend on the optimization option of GCC.

Comment: The question is tagged as `c`, although the compiler invocation suggests that the code is compiled as C++.

Comment: Yes, gcc can optimize a simple constant string print from `printf()` to `puts()`, as the latter performs better... since you replaced the standard library puts() with a local symbol, that is what you get.  If you use -O0 instead of -O2, you should actually call `printf()`

Comment: OK, retagging and editing title.

Comment: BTW, your code looks like C code but you compile it as C++11; why do you do that? If you want to code in C++11 use `std::cout<<"hello world" << std::endl;`

Comment: Good point; was just a copypasta compile line. Still get same result without -std=c++11 and -O2. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, a compiler may replace a call to `printf` by an *equivalent* call to `puts`.

Because you defined your own function `puts` with the same name as a standard library function, your program's behavior is undefined.

Reference: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.1.3:

> All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses [this includes `puts`] are always reserved for use as identifiers with external linkage.
>   `...`
>   If the program declares or defines an identifier in a
>   context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved
>   identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.

If you remove your own `puts` function and examine an assembly listing, you *might* find a call to `puts` in the generated code where you called `printf` in the source code. (I've seen gcc perform this particular optimization.)

Comment: (Disclaimer: Only in hosted implementations)

Answer (score 12):

It depends upon the compiler and the optimization level. Most recent versions of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), on some common systems, with some optimizations, are able to do such an optimization (replacing a simple `printf` with `puts`, which AFAIU is legal w.r.t. standards like C99)

You should enable warnings when compiling (e.g. try first to compile with `gcc -Wall -g`, then debug with `gdb`, then when you are confident with your code compile it with `gcc -Wall -O2`)

BTW, redefining `puts` is really really ugly, unless you do it on purpose (i.e. are coding your own C library, and then you have to obey to the standards). You are getting some [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) about possible consequences of UB). Actually you should avoid redefining names mentioned in the standard, unless you really really know well what you are doing and what is happening inside the compiler.

Also, if you compiled with static linking like `gcc -Wall -static -O main.c -o yourprog` I'll bet that the linker would have complained (about multiple definition of `puts`).

But IMNSHO your code is plain wrong, and you know that.

Also, you could compile to get the assembler, e.g. with `gcc -fverbose-asm -O -S`; and you could even ask `gcc` to spill a *lot* of "dump" files, with `gcc -fdump-tree-all -O` which might help you understanding what `gcc` is doing.

Again, this particular optimization is *valid* and very *useful* : the `printf` routine of any libc has to "interpret" *at runtime* the print format string (handling `%s` etc ... specially); this is in practice quite slow. A good compiler is right in avoiding calling `printf` (and replacing with `puts`) when possible.

BTW `gcc` is not the only compiler doing that optimization. `clang` also does it.

Also, if you compile with

```
gcc -ffreestanding -O2 almo.c -o almo
```

the `almo` program shows `Hello world.`

---

If you want another fancy and surprizing optimization, try to compile

```
// file bas.c
#include <stdlib.h>
int f (int x, int y) {
  int r;
  int* p = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
  p[0] = x;
  p[1] = y;
  r = p[0]+p[1];
  free (p);
  return r;
}
```

with `gcc -O2 -fverbose-asm -S bas.c` then look into `bas.s`; you won't see any call to `malloc` or to `free` (actually, no `call` machine instruction is emitted) and again, `gcc` is *right* to optimize (and so does `clang`)!

<sup>PS: Gnu/Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64; `gcc` is version 4.9.1, `clang` is version 3.4.2</sup>

Comment: Good point; just tried with gcc, so the question stands, and thanks for the answer. Will do some more investigation and accept an answer later. :)

Comment: I do know it's wrong. I was curious about why it does this.

Comment: Wow that's a pretty cool (the fancy and surprizing optimization)

Answer (score 1):

Try `ltrace` on your executable. You will see that `printf` gets replaced by `puts` call by the compiler. This depends on the way you called `printf`

An interesting reading on this is [here](http://www.ciselant.de/projects/gcc_printf/gcc_printf.html)

Answer (score -1):

Presumably, your library's printf() calls puts ().

Your puts() is replacing the library version.

Comment: Actually, the `printf` is *not* calling `puts` at *runtime*, but the *compiler* is right to replace the `printf` with `puts` at *compile-time*

Comment: If that were the case then OPs definition of `puts` would be infinite recursion and never output anything.