# Some one can explain this behavior ? just 2 lines of code

Tags: c

Kindly explain this snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int puts(const char *str) {
    fputs("Hello world!\n", stdout);
}

int main() {
    printf("Goodbye\n");
}
```

Output : `Hello world!` return 13

Comment: C90 and ignored diagnostics?

Comment: GCC replaces the call of the puts and printf simple string + newline.

Comment: Just shows what you can do by replacing innocent-looking library functions with your own code. After all, you could call home there, or transfer cent fractions if this is banking software, or insert a line into /etc/passwd if this is ever running as root.

Comment: btw: Is there a away to access stdlib's puts in this program? I'd guess not with standard means. Perhaps with some gcc magic? Because for the egg of a disgruntled employee the new puts should probably emulate the old puts, which would be easiest done by calling it after executing the malicious bit.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: You are already far outside the standard, so of course you need more UB or compiler-magic.

Comment: @Deduplicator Do you know any?

Comment: This code isn't standard compliant, as the user is not allowed to re-define standard library identifiers.

Answer (score 10):

It is compiler specific. You get this behavior with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Here are some details.

- since you `#include <stdio.h>` (actually because you are in a hosted environment) the `puts` is that of the C99 standard, and redefining it is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)
- the GCC compiler has some optimizations to transform some `printf` to a sequence of *faster* `puts`. This is legal, since you have included `<stdio.h>` (and the C99 standard defines what `printf` should do in that case; GCC goes thru `__builtin_printf` as an intermediate step)

If you compile with `-ffreestanding` you won't observe that.

Your question is very close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25816659/841108); so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25816706/841108) is also relevant.

Comment: No probably about it, it's straight UB. And it is legal because he's compiling for a hosted environment, the includes don't matter.

Comment: This is legal, since it does not change the observable behavior for a conforming program.

Answer (score 7):

I compiled the program with `gcc x.c -S -o-`. It gave me

```
[...]
main:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushl   %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        .cfi_offset 5, -8
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
        andl    $-16, %esp
        subl    $16, %esp
        movl    $.LC1, (%esp)
        call    puts
        leave
        .cfi_restore 5
        .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
```

so indeed the `printf` call is replaced with `puts` in GCC, as they have the same semantics.

Answer (score 6):

My guess would be that the compiler changes the call to `printf()` into a call to `puts()`, since there's no need for `printf()` due to no formatting. Also the string is terminated by a newline, which fits `puts()`. The compiler didn't see your scary overload of a library function coming, so it got "fooled".